# Emergency Mode Issue on SUSE Linux HPC System

Tags: boot, suse, system-recovery, nvme

I have a head node and 4 worker nodes for high-performance computing (HPC).

Recently, I had to turn it off for maintenance at our data center. I tried to turn the system back on, but I encountered an error message stating

```
[ 5.215623][ C14] nvme0: Identify(0x6), Invalid Field in Command (sct 0x0 / sc 0x2)
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):
```

and it seems to be stuck in a loop.

Initially, I selected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> as suggested to boot into the default mode, but unfortunately, it just recycles back to the same emergency mode error every time.

A couple of things that might be relevant:

- I wasn't aware, but it seems an external USB was left plugged into the system's back when I turned it on after maintenance. I'm not entirely sure if this could be causing the issue, but it's worth mentioning.
- Each node requires two power cables plugged into the power adapter. During the reconnection, I realized that one of the power cables for a node was not initially connected to a power source. However, I have fixed this issue, and now all nodes are receiving power as required.

I'm not a Linux expert, so I'm a bit lost as to what could be causing this problem. I've tried searching for solutions online, but nothing seems to be working for me.

If any of you have encountered a similar issue or have expertise with SUSE Linux and HPC systems, I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this "emergency mode" problem.

Comment: I have been told that it might have to do with /etc/fstab misconfigured. I any body has step by step instruction for me to test this theory?

Comment: What is the **full** message that appears on the screen? Do you see `Give root password for maintenance (or press Control D to continue):`? If so, you can just type the root password instead of CTRL-D, and you'll get into the shell. Then you can view and edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Here is the full message that appears on the screen: [    5.215623][    C14] nvme0: Identify(0x6), Invalid Field in Command (sct 0x0 / you are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default"  or "exit" to boot into default mode. Given root password for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):                                                                                       


I did press Control-D but system reboots with the same message

Comment: Read my comment again: **you can just type the root password instead of CTRL-D, and you'll get into the shell.**

Comment: yes I can type the root password and get into the shell but since I do not have lots of Linux experience I'm not sure what I need to do further.

Comment: Please add extra/new information by editing the question. Searching through comments is difficult and error-prone. After getting into the shell, did you try the suggested commands? Did `journalctl -xb` provide any information?

Comment: The nvme error appears to just be noise - https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/Ykyf5Zuz1W8yHhNY@zx2c4.com/T/ - unplug the USB, login as root and check journalctl.